# Using the ith minus value in Data Structures

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, iterator

Every time I stumble upon a DSA problem, I always see the usage of something such as i - array dot length, i - array[i], i + variabke, or ith - j - 1, especially inside an array. I always thought it would be a negative number index, making it undefined, yet I see most programmers constantly using this formula for anything. what does this mean and how does it work?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're saying. Could you maybe actually structure your slightly overlength sentence better, and since you say "I always see…", actually provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

What I think that you're struggling with is a consequence of 0-indexing.

As [Dijkstra explains](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html), programming languages have a variety of different array indexing notations that they could use.  For a variety of reasons, including the ones that Dijkstra gives, most languages have settled on the following notational rule.

```
the index of an array element is its distance from the start
```

Therefore the FIRST element appears at index 0.  The SECOND appears at index 1.  And if the array has length `n`, the LAST element appears at index `n-1`.  Any algorithm that has to deal with array indexes explicitly has to be aware of this, and will often wind up with what might appear to be randomly place -1s because of it.  But if you think through the logic, they are completely logical, and serve an important purpose.

Usually we don't have to worry about it.  For example in Python you would type:

```
for x in some_list:
    ...
```

And if you need the indexes you'd write:

```
for x in range(len(some_list)):
    ...
```

In a low-level language like C you have to be explicit, but you just get used to writing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ...
}
```

And so this detail fades into the background in the most natural ways to write code.  (The fact that it easily does with few errors is part of why this convention was adopted!)  But when you need to think explicitly about it, you need to be aware of it.